# $_POST, image forms and mysql.How to get them working together?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, function

I'm trying to get a website working. What I have are basically two images displayed (random, taken out of a mySQL database). What I need to do is (when the user clicks one of the images) the following:

- Update the page, passing the info about the selected image (submit form);
- Add one piece of data to the database (upvote the image)

I need to use $_POST to pass an array of values to the next page. So I thought:

```
<form name="input" action="the_page.php" method="POST">
<input type="image" 
       name="img" 
       src="image.png"
       value ="dat1[\"data1\",\"data2\",\"data3\"]">
       <!-- If value must be a single string, I'll use hidden inputs-->
</form>

<form name="input" action="the_page.php" method="POST">
<input type="image" 
       name="img" 
       src="image2.png"
       value ="dat2[\"data1\",\"data2\",\"data3\"]">
</form>
```

Then I can upvote the selected image on the mySQL database with a little php upvote() function that updates the record. The upvoting process is done when the new page is loaded. From this, I have a couple questions:

1. I'm guessing the images will act as buttons, right? (They are supposed to submit the form, hence refreshing the page). If not, how can I achieve this? I'm unable to do it with a link (since I can't add the values to it). Maybe a javascript function? But I don't know how to submit the form that way either...
2. Once the page is reloaded, does it mean that only the data from one form has been submited, so I can retrieve the data by simply calling the PHP variable $_POST['img'] and get an array back?

EDIT: I now managed to get everything working, slightly similar to what I proposed initially. Thanks for the AJAX suggestion though, since it was what helped me solve it (looked up AJAX tutorials, found solution).

Here's my solution:

```
<?php
echo "<form name=\"input\" action=\"F2F.php\" method=\"POST\">";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name =\"table\" value=\"".$table1."\">";
echo "<input type=\"image\" name=\"nom\" src=\"".$IMG_Route1."\" value =\"".$Nom_base1."\" border=\"0\">";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

(where the image goes)

and then, on the header:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['nom']||$_POST['nom_x']){
    if (!$_POST['nom']){
        echo 'Could not retrieve name. $_POST[\'nom_x\'] = '.$_POST['nom_x']. mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    if (!$_POST['table']){
        echo 'Could not retrieve table. $_POST[\'table\'] = '.$_POST['table']. mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    upvote($_POST['table'],$_POST['nom']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you try it first? That's a good way to see if it works. We can't help you fix something that hasn't been tried first.

Comment: You could do that with AJAX in no time, also, i think it would be the easiest way

Comment: I did try this before posting. Array didn't work at first so I used hidden inputs. I still can't get to work the submission of the forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one form and a set of radio buttons to simplify things a bit. Clicking on the label will toggle the radio button. You can use commas to separate multiple values for each checkbox, which you can then abstract later on (see below)

```
<form name="input" action="the_page.php" method="POST">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                <img src="whatever.jpg" />
                <input type="radio" name="selectedImage" id="img1" value="12,16,19" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <img src="whatever2.jpg" />
                <input type="radio" name="selectedImage" id="img2" value="12,16,19" />
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

You can detect when the radio button is selected by adding a listener for the change event, then submit the form.

```
$('input[name="selectedImage"]').change(function() {
    $('form[name="input"]').submit();
});
```

To abstract the multiple values, you can then explode the form result with PHP, which will return an array of the values.

```
$selectedImageValues = array();
$selectedImageValues = explode(",", $_POST['selectedImage']);
```

From there you can pull the different values out and save the data to the database.